# How to emulate NFC Tag on android?

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I need to develop an app on Android which can act as an NFC Tag types 1..5, so that it can be read by Android and iOS devices.

Is it possible ?

Comment: for mifare classic cards you can see my repository:https://github.com/codes29/RFIDReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various google sample on [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidCardEmulation) that does what you want.

Comment: thanks. The samples involve setting AID on both sides in order to recognize each other. Is it possible to set AID on iOS app?

Comment: Or basically, is it possible to read from iOS, info from tags that are emulated this way on Android devices?

Comment: Yes, there are free apps on the app store. If you need to do it in a programatic way you need to look at SDK. @drek